# Error encountered: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass-multioutput and binary targets

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, random-forest

```
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

file = './BBC.csv'
df = read_csv(file)

array = df.values  
X = array[:, 0:11] 
Y = array[:, 11] 

test_size = 0.30 
seed = 45 
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)

model = RandomForestClassifier()  
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

result = model.score(X_test, X_test)

print("Accuracy: %.3f%%") % (result*100.0)
```

dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ar1c9yuv5x774cv/BBC.csv?dl=0

I have encountered this error:

Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass-multioutput and binary targets

If i'm not wrong RandomForest should be able to handle both classes (classification) and means (regression). Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Checked your dataset. So for classification task, your problem lies in your code.

`result = model.score(X_test, X_test)`

Note that the parameter here should be `X_test` and `Y_test`

-----kind of off-topic-----
If you want to use RandomForest for regression, you probably should call [RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)

Comment: however, my target variable is dichotomous, isn't classifier the module to use?

Comment: ahhh yes, my careless mistake. thank you for your time, really helped me move on. appreciate it